# How to push an object to array in angular2 and typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

i have defined an array as follows,

```
markers: marker[] = [
    {
      lat: 51.673858,
      lng: 7.815982,
      label: 'A',
      draggable: true
    }
  ];
```

i am getting data from rest service and push the new object to markers.

```
private data: any;
  findLocation(): void {
    let result;
    result =   this.geoService.loaddata(this.location)
     .subscribe(data => {
       result = data;
       console.log(result);
       this.markers.push({'lat':results[0].geometry.location.lat,'lng':results[0].geometry.location.lng})
     });
  }
```

it throws an error saying file:

> message: 'Argument of type '{ 'lat': any; }' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'marker'.   Property 'lng' is missing in type '{
>   'lat': any; }'.'

result is

> {    "results" : [
>         {
>            "address_components" : [
>               {
>                  "long_name" : "Colombo",
>                  "short_name" : "Colombo",
>                  "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
>               },
>               {
>                  "long_name" : "Colombo",
>                  "short_name" : "Colombo",
>                  "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
>               },
>               {
>                  "long_name" : "Western Province",
>                  "short_name" : "WP",
>                  "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
>               },
>               {
>                  "long_name" : "Sri Lanka",
>                  "short_name" : "LK",
>                  "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
>               }
>            ],
>            "formatted_address" : "Colombo, Sri Lanka",
>            "geometry" : {
>               "bounds" : {
>                  "northeast" : {
>                     "lat" : 6.9812866,
>                     "lng" : 79.8900852
>                  },
>                  "southwest" : {
>                     "lat" : 6.862390700000001,
>                     "lng" : 79.8223258
>                  }
>               },
>               "location" : {
>                  "lat" : 6.9270786,
>                  "lng" : 79.861243
>               },
>               "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
>               "viewport" : {
>                  "northeast" : {
>                     "lat" : 6.980584400000001,
>                     "lng" : 79.8900852
>                  },
>                  "southwest" : {
>                     "lat" : 6.8625113,
>                     "lng" : 79.8225192
>                  }
>               }
>            },
>            "place_id" : "ChIJA3B6D9FT4joRjYPTMk0uCzI",
>            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
>         }    ],    "status" : "OK" }

Comment: why two `lat` in your json?

Comment: What's in result[0]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have subscribed your data to `result`, not `results`.

```
private data: any;
  findLocation(): void {
    let result;
    // no use for "result" below
    // result = this.geoService.loaddata(this.location)
    // use the following instead
    this.geoService.loaddata(this.location)
     .subscribe(data => {
       result = data;
       console.log(result);
       this.markers.push({'lat':results[0].geometry.location.lat,'lng':results[0].geometry.location.lng})
     });
  }
```

so your push should look like:

```
this.markers.push({'lat':result[0].geometry.location.lat,'lng':result[0].geometry.location.lng})
         });
```

But this too will throw an error because in markers you have also declared `label` and `draggable`, so you need to push values to those attributes too.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a simple typo:

```
this.markers.push({
    'lat': results[0].geometry.location.lat,
    'lat': results[0].geometry.location.lng
})
```

should be:

```
this.markers.push({
    'lat': results[0].geometry.location.lat,
    'lng': results[0].geometry.location.lng
})
```

Comment: Do you still get the same error? Given the shape of the data you've added to your question, the hierarchy looks correct.

Comment: ok sorry guys, i was missing the other two properties label and draggable

Comment: For anyone trying to find the difference, note the "lat" / "lng" on the second input. Took me long to find.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have a typo there, you access a variable called `results` but there is only `result`.

Second, that result variable makes little sense. Try this:

```
// private data: any; // Remove this field
findLocation(): void {
    // no result variable here
    this.geoService.loaddata(this.location)
    .subscribe(results => { // declare results this way
        console.log(results);
        this.markers.push({
          'lat':results[0].geometry.location.lat,
          'lnt':results[0].geometry.location.lng
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    this.geoService.loaddata(this.location)
       .subscribe(data => {
       result = data;
       this.markers.push({'lat':data.geometry.location.lat,'lng':data.geometry.location.lng})
    });
```